# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess'. no other solutions found

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio-2015

Simply this problem while trying to run my code. Any help please?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was
>   supplied for an assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: Oracle.DataAccess |
>   Domain ID: 2 WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly
>   display name is provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading
>   an incorrect assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully
>   specified textual identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the
>   simple name, version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See
>   whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more
>   information and common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///c:/users/tomas.filip/documents/visual studio
>   2015/Projects/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = c:\users\tomas.filip\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\bin Calling assembly :
>   (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\users\tomas.filip\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\web.config LOG:
>   Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\tomas.filip\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tomas.filip/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/adc42dc8/2881b8ff/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tomas.filip/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/adc42dc8/2881b8ff/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///c:/users/tomas.filip/documents/visual studio
>   2015/Projects/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/bin/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
>   terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +92    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9984344 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1649.1

end the debug output...

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   in mscorlib.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException'
>   in mscorlib.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\7a812709\0000c41d_ffa6d001\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\d6536d09\00b6e5f2_c710ce01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\6e026361\0091f978_739fce01\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\4c52a744\00e3a22d_4f82ce01\AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\e9d7abbc\004309b4_51acd201\ClosedXML.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\ae19faef\0092bfc0_0491ce01\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\ac2201e7\0061c907_bb54d001\EntityFramework.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\1bbcd705\0061c907_bb54d001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\866a7f55\18cae353_34d5d201\Interop.OracleInProcServer.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\7c714460\d8ba8d53_34d5d201\Interop.ORADCLib.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\a5b5bf12\282f2d54_34d5d201\Interop.ORAOLEDBLib.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\85cf5333\00735a7f_1b4bd201\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\32fb9c51\000f650e_7750d201\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\e8e5c1a7\00b970bc_7750d201\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\81b6a78f\0042be3d_cb4fd201\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\70d3f26e\00575f8a_7750d201\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\5be8b1c8\00b970bc_7750d201\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\eb3b6075\00f88c69_ca4fd201\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\40876f78\0069051d_358dce01\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\18504aa8\0071b0e2_1f6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\05fe289a\0071b0e2_1f6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\e3a80eac\0071b0e2_1f6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\8d39697c\003e13d0_2c27cf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\f83d9bc6\003b0384_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\f809ae9b\00956586_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\a372e6a5\00efc788_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\6ec0b560\00c29687_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\1c2895f6\00efc788_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\bd37c867\00efc788_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\f7ef9e7c\001cf989_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\ffc6945f\001cf989_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\ffd4ed1d\00492a8b_7e47d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\3838834b\002eee49_e2aace01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\51e9febf\000fe44f_e2aace01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\e19b9e68\00630fa1_89cbcc01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\tomas.filip\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\adc42dc8\2881b8ff\assembly\dl3\98c86cc9\0082b57b_49afcf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. Exception thrown:
>   'System.BadImageFormatException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Web.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.Web\v4.0_4.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.Web.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131401828468112282): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. The program '[8852] iisexpress.exe' has exited

with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Did you install / use Oracle's 32bit or 64bit distributions? It looks like your app is running in 32bit and trying to load 64bit assets (or vice versa) which doesn't work.

Comment: I did install everything 64bit, how is my app running in 32 bit? any way to change it?

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are using Oracle's 64 bit components but per default IIS Express runs in 32 bit mode. To change it, under Tools > Options, set this setting:

[image]

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: A day savior, ty @martin-ullrich!

Comment: Fixed the issue. Thank you!